# Navegação via programação React Navigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Existe alguma forma de fazer uma navegação programática usando a lib @react-navigation no React Native?

Estou fazendo validações fora dos arquivos do React .JSX e queria fazer um "push" em uma rota caso alguma condição for atendida

Comment: Se você passar o objeto `history` para essa função, consegue usar `history.push`.  Não sei se faz sentido essa lógica, acho que tirar a navegação do componente pode dificultar o entendimento do código, já que uma função externa estaria modificando o estado da aplicação.

Comment: O hook useNavigation não ajudaria?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando uma referência do Navigation Container do React Navigation conforme [documentação](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/) e dentro da função fora do componente chamando esta referência.